# Array created in a Redux thunk is not being passed properly to the State tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a React/Redux project that makes a couple calls to an S3 bucket to grab images, and then render them into the app.

I'm finding that for some reason, I cannot iterate through the array that I set in my state tree as a result of those calls to render them onto the app. I believe that I may be dealing with an **array-like object** or something within the Promises I created caused this mutation to occur.

First, I have this file in a folder titled **utils**:

```
const bucketName = 'foo';
const roleARN = 'arn:aws:s3:::foo';
const identityPoolId = 'us-west-2:anActualIdHere';

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId
  })
});

const bucket = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: bucketName,
  }
});

const textDecoder = new TextDecoder('utf8');

export function listObjects (callback) {
  return bucket.listObjects((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('error: ', error);
      return;
    }

    callback(data.Contents);
  });
}

export function getSingleObject (key) {
  let getObject = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bucket.getObject({
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key
    }, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('error: ', error);
      }

      resolve(data.Body.toString('base64'));
    });
  })

  return getObject.then((result) => {
    return result;
  })
}
```

What happens here is that `listObjects` will return an array of all items in a specific S3 bucket.

Then, the `getSingleObject` function grabs a single object's contents based on a key provided in that list of all items, grabbing its Uint8Array and converting it to a base-64 string.

These two functions are called in a thunk action:

```
import { listObjects, getSingleObject } from '../utils/index.js';

export function loadPhotos () {
  return function (dispatch) {
    listObjects((results) => {
      let photos = [];

      let mapPhotosToArray = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        results.forEach((singlePhoto) => {
          let getSinglePhoto = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(getSingleObject(singlePhoto.Key));
          });

          getSinglePhoto.then((result) => {
            photos.push(result);
          });
        });
        resolve(photos);
      })

      mapPhotosToArray.then((result) => {
        dispatch(savePhotos(result));
      });
    });
  }
}

function savePhotos (photos) {
  return {
    type: 'GET_PHOTOS',
    photos
  }
}
```

`loadPhotos` is the thunk action exposed to my Redux containers. It returns a function that first calls the `listObjects` function in the **utils** file, passing it a callback that creates an array called `photos`.

Then, it creates a new Promise that loops through the results array returned by the `listObjects` utility function. In each iteration of this results array, I instantiate another new Promise that calls the `getSingleObject` utility.

Within that iteration, I push the results of `getSingleObject` into the `photos` array created within the callback passed into `listObjects`.

The last thing I do in the `loadPhotos` thunk action is call the outer Promise and then dispatch the result to the `savePhotos` action, which finally dispatches the payload object to the store for my reducer to catch.

This is how my **reducer** looks:

```
const defaultState = {
  photos: []
}

const photos = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_PHOTOS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        photos: action.photos
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default photos;
```

Here is how I've set up the entry point to the app:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, compose, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import photos from './reducers/';

import App from './components/app';

import styles from './styles/styles.css';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(photos, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

This is the App component rendered:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import AllPhotos from '../containers/AllPhotos';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

import '../styles/styles.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Navbar />
        <AllPhotos />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the AllPhotos container it renders:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import AllPhotos from '../components/AllPhotos';

import {
  loadPhotos
} from '../actions/index.js';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadPhotos: () => {
      dispatch(loadPhotos());
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    photos: state.photos
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllPhotos);
```

And finally, this is the AllPhotos component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default class AllPhotos extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.loadPhotos();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        { this._renderImages() }
      </div>
    )
  }

  _renderImages () {
    _.map(this.props.photos, (image) => {
      return (
        <img
          src={ 'data:image/png;base64,' + image }
          width={ 480 }
        />
      )
    })
  }
}
```

This is what happens when I attempt to log `this.props.photos` within `_renderImages`:

[image: First Image]

The first log occurs before the photos array is populated and loaded into my state.

However, if I were to log the length of `this.props.photos` in the same area that I log just the array itself, this is what I see:

[image]

When I call Array.isArray on `this.props.photos` in that same line, this is what I get:[image]

I have also attempted to convert this into an array using `Array.from`, but have not been successful.

Going a bit deeper, I attempted to find the length of the `photos` array from the action payload in my reducer, and still received `0` as the output. I also tried this within the `savePhotos` action, and found the same result.

As a result, I believe I may have not written my Promises correctly. Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should fetch your data in componentDidMount: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try rewriting `listObjects` and `getSingleObject` to return Promises and utilising [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Then you can write `loadPhotos`

```
export function loadPhotos () {
  return function (dispatch) {
    listObjects().then((results) => 
      Promise.all(results.map((singlePhoto) => getSingleObject(singlePhoto.Key)))
        .then((result) => dispatch(savePhotos(result)))
    )
  }
}
```